# How to disable button for 3 hrs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with an app in which there is a need that if button is pressed then it should be disable for 3 hours and I didn't find any solution yet. Is there any way to achieve this task ? Even the app may close or user do other task on other screens .Please help!

Comment: Have you tried IgnorePointer?then add a timer on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think You can Use **Timer** method in flutter to achive this:

```
   Timer.periodic(. // assing new timer to our variable.
    Duration(
      milliseconds: 500,
    ), (timer) {

      }
```

Comment: I tried but when you move to other screen it crashed and when you navigate to same screen then it show button enabled

Comment: then why not u used some state managment tech

Comment: try to use riverpod this is simple

Comment: Apart from your state management (Provider for example) you might want to use shared_preferences to store the date/time when the button should become available again. 3 hour indicates that you want to maintain this even if the app is closed for a while.

Comment: @Andrija Yes that's might be the possible solution which I was thinking. That's shared preferences but here is 1 think I want to ask that can I store multiple keys like "userdata", "date", etc on different times in shared preferences. Because that's the only possible and best solution

Comment: @Arslan yes u can store that

Comment: Yes, in shared preferences you can store multiple keys. You can even store entire JSON objects - you just need to encode/decode it with json.encode/json.decode. So under your keys "userdata", "date" - you can store simple objects - strings, integers; or you can store complex JSON objects.